# Div content stretch when checking on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a responsive page here and i have aligned it to center. But i want that whenever i open that page in a mobile window i want to text to stretch and there should be no white space at both right or left side. How can i achieve this? I am using bootstrap 4 and i just need the white space on both sides to be removed when i am viewing the page in mobile

```css
hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.alignLeft {
    float: left;
}

.indented{padding-left: 50pt; padding-right: 50pt;}

.col-sm-9 {
    background-color: white; 
}

img {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}



h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

h4, p {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: justify !important;
}

.para1 {
    text-align: center !important;
}


h4:first-child {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 20px !important;
}

h4:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: left !important;
}

p:first-child { 
    text-align: center !important; 
}

p:nth-child(3) {
    text-align: left !important;
    float:  left !important;
}

.center3 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 65%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.columns1 {
    align-self: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .thumb {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url(https://ibb.co/d7s9Fe);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
  }
.center2{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 65%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    
}

i.material-icons {
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
}

p {
    font-size: 17px !important;
}

.center2 .footer {
    bottom: 0;
}

.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    padding-left: 300px;
 
}

.jumbotron {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white; 
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


.navbar {
    align-items: center;
}

.center1 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 140px;
}

.footer-copyright {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    padding-right: 70px;
}


.footer {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    background-color: grey; 
    bottom: 0;
    margin : auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 12;
    font-size: 10px;
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.footer a {
    background-color: transparent;
}
a {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.container-fluid {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="center3">
      <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
        <i class="fa fa-cubes"></i> GEP
        <span class="header-logo-text">Learning Management System</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="center2">
        <div class="columns1 text-center">
 
          <div class="thumb"></div>
          <h4 align="left" style="margin-top: 100px;">
            <span style="margin-left: 20px;">School Name</span>
          </h4>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <hr>
          <section>
            <div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                </p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <br>
          <br>
          <section>
            <div>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://ibb.co/d7s9Fe" alt="Smiley face" style="float:right;width:400px;height:200px;">
              <p>
                <span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span>
                <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
              </p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <section>
            <div>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://ibb.co/d7s9Fe" alt="Smiley face" style="float:left;width:400px;height:200px;">
              <p>
                <span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span>
                <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat.
              </p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <section>
            <div>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://ibb.co/d7s9Fe" alt="Smiley face" style="float:right;width:400px;height:200px;">
              <p>
                <span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span>
                <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat.
              </p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <section>
            <div>
              <h3><u>Address</u></h3>
              <i class="material-icons" style="color:red; ">location_on</i>
              <span id="txt1" style="font-size: 15px;">Address,County,City,District</span>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
      <div>
        <a href="">
          <h3>Gep Learning Management System</h3>
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You should be use this simple trick `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .center2{width: 100%;}
}`

Comment: you are right but this makes the text wrap around the images which i do not want. any way to avoid that?

Comment: So you want to set full width your image ?

Comment: yes image also should be of full width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use media query:

Must read about [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Can you please try.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .center2{width: 100%;}
  .center2 img {
    width: 100% !important;
    float: left !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
}
```

Hope this help.

Let me know further clarification.

```css
hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.alignLeft {
    float: left;
}

.indented{padding-left: 50pt; padding-right: 50pt;}

.col-sm-9 {
    background-color: white; 
}

img {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}



h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

h4, p {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: justify !important;
}

.para1 {
    text-align: center !important;
}


h4:first-child {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 20px !important;
}

h4:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: left !important;
}

p:first-child { 
    text-align: center !important; 
}

p:nth-child(3) {
    text-align: left !important;
    float:  left !important;
}

.center3 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 65%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.columns1 {
    align-self: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .thumb {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url(https://ibb.co/d7s9Fe);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
  }
.center2{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 65%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    
}

i.material-icons {
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
}

p {
    font-size: 17px !important;
}

.center2 .footer {
    bottom: 0;
}

.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    padding-left: 300px;
 
}

.jumbotron {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white; 
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


.navbar {
    align-items: center;
}

.center1 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 140px;
}

.footer-copyright {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    padding-right: 70px;
}


.footer {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    background-color: grey; 
    bottom: 0;
    margin : auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 12;
    font-size: 10px;
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.footer a {
    background-color: transparent;
}
a {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.container-fluid {
    background-color: white;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .center2{width: 100%;}
  .center2 img {
    width: 100% !important;
    float: left !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="center3">
      <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
        <i class="fa fa-cubes"></i> GEP
        <span class="header-logo-text">Learning Management System</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="center2">
        <div class="columns1 text-center">
 
          <div class="thumb"></div>
          <h4 align="left" style="margin-top: 100px;">
            <span style="margin-left: 20px;">School Name</span>
          </h4>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <hr>
          <section>
            <div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                </p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <br>
          <br>
          <section>
            <div>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://ibb.co/d7s9Fe" alt="Smiley face" style="float:right;width:400px;height:200px;">
              <p>
                <span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span>
                <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
              </p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <section>
            <div>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://ibb.co/d7s9Fe" alt="Smiley face" style="float:left;width:400px;height:200px;">
              <p>
                <span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span>
                <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat.
              </p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <section>
            <div>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://ibb.co/d7s9Fe" alt="Smiley face" style="float:right;width:400px;height:200px;">
              <p>
                <span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span>
                <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat.
              </p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <section>
            <div>
              <h3><u>Address</u></h3>
              <i class="material-icons" style="color:red; ">location_on</i>
              <span id="txt1" style="font-size: 15px;">Address,County,City,District</span>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
      <div>
        <a href="">
          <h3>Gep Learning Management System</h3>
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: and happy independence day to you too :D